# how to make textbox to fill the gap between 2 other controls in html

Tags: html

I have radiobutton list and then comes a textbox then a button

these suppose to be in the same line

the radios are in far left and the button is on the far right and the textbox to fill the gap between them

[image]

I built this code but did not get the right results

```
            <div style="background-color: yellow; display: inline-block;">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdxCoding" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Text</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Font</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Colour</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Number</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: aqua; display: inline-block">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRepText" Placeholder="Search Text" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: fuchsia; display: inline-block">
                <asp:Button ID="btnRepSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnRepSearch_Click" Font-Names="Courier New" />
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) for that.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.container > div {
  padding: 5px;
}

.test-input {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.test-input input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="background-color: yellow">
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
    <label for="male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
    <label for="female">Female</label>
  </div>
  <div class="test-input" style="background-color: aqua">
      <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: fuchsia">
      <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but i can see test-input class only defines , I cannot see test-radio and test-button?

Comment: They are not needed since I decided to set padding on every container child by .container > div instead on every .test-xxx separetly. But this code is only proof of concept since you are using some kind of framework anyway, so short answer will be "use flexboxes.".

Comment: Thanks but I think you removed test-input instead of test-radio